# JavaScript - Why am I getting unexpected uncaught error 'length', 'splice' etc of undefined?

Tags: javascript, class, object, jasmine

Thanks for blocking me. Not sure how to get unblocked but would just like to ask a question... I merge two accounts and thought that'd help considering I've been quite active on the other account. I was actively helping the community, in fact...

Comment: it looks like 'this.input' is undefined. var bob = new Bob(); <= you didn't pass the input argument.

Comment: Your code is unclear. Do you want `Bob` objects to be filled with input at the time of their creation - or not?

Comment: In your hey definition you are not passing any parameter, but in the test you are. I think you need to clean up your code a little.

Comment: As a sidenote, `/[a - z]/.test(whatever)` doesn't do what you think it does. Whitespace is meaningful inside regex.

Comment: You're right Stef! Actually this exercise is from exercism.io, and the tests are ready-built for you to kick off. I had to change one of the tests because the README.md stated something that wasn't in the test. Looks like they've also forgotten to pass in a string to Bob! Thanks for clearing that up, my bad for not being attentive enough.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was no argument passed when the new class was called! My fault for not being attentive enough. Thanks for your answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that `Bob()` takes an argument `(input)` and in the test there is no argument passed to `Bob()`.

Similarly, `Bob.hey()` does not take an argument while a string is being passed to it.

If the above is valid then `bob.spec.js` should be:

**bob.spec.js**

```
var Bob = require('./bob.js');

describe('Bob', function () {
  var bob = new Bob('Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to.');

  it('stating something', function () {
    var result = bob.hey();
    expect(result).toEqual('Whatever.');
  });
```